# Child and parent not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three circles with the same features except color and position inside a table class, but in the css isn't getting the features the child.

```
  <div class="table circles">
      <div class="circle-1"><span>text1</span></div>
      <div class="circle-2"><span>text2</span></div>
      <div class="circle-3"><span>text3</span></div>
   </div>
```

And in the scss:

```
    .circle{
       width: 84px;
       height: 84px;
       display: inline-block;
       border-radius: 48px;

       .circle-1{
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px $b1;
          background-color:$b1;
       }
       .circle-2{
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px $b2;
          background-color:$b2;
          margin-left:150px;
       }
       .circle-3{
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px $b3;
          background-color:$b3;
          margin-left:300px;
       }
    }
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: None of the elements have the class `.circle` ?

Comment: And you didn't close the first one

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/djv4gufn/

Comment: The CSS you posted looks as though it's SCSS rather than actual CSS.  Have you compiled that into CSS first, or are you calling the SCSS file?

Comment: Ok, it was just to add div to circle. In the link works fine and in my code not.

Comment: I'm on the scss sorry. A mistake.

Comment: Also, in the SCSS (and therefore CSS) the class is "circle", but in the HTML the outer div has the class "circles" (additional S), so it's not going to pick up the nesting when the SCSS is compiled.

Comment: I made some changes and solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ek505903/

It looks is SCSS code, but the .circle class is missing from HTML.

```
<div class="table circles">
  <div class="circle circle-1"><span>text1</span></div>
  <div class="circle circle-2"><span>text2</span></div>
  <div class="circle circle-3"><span>text3</span></div>
</div>


.circle {
   width: 84px;
   height: 84px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 48px;
   text-align: center;
}

.circle span {
    /*to center the text vertically use the same value as .circle height*/
    line-height: 84px;
}

.circle-1{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black;
  background-color: red;
}

.circle-2{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left:150px;
}

.circle-3{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don;t want to modify HTML code, you could try this one:

```
.circles {
  & > div { // affect direct child div (circle-1,circle-2,circle-3)
   width: 84px;
   height: 84px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 48px;
 }
 .circle-1{
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px $b1;
      background-color:$b1;
   }
 .circle-2{
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px $b2;
      background-color:$b2;
      margin-left:150px;
   }
 .circle-3{
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px $b3;
      background-color:$b3;
      margin-left:300px;
   }
}
```